# Force stop running ActiveRecord, avoid mysql max_execution_time

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

We have app with specs: Ruby 2.6.5, Rails 4.2.11, MySQL 5.7.33 (max_execution_time = 1200000, 20minutes)

With huge data, for example, company data, sometimes when we do query it took time so long. So I decided to use `Timeout::timeout` to force stop query, but it seems won't work.

This is the sample code

```rb
begin
  max_time = 600 # 10minutes

  Timeout::timeout(max_time) do
    company = Company.where(location: 'West').last
  end
rescue => e
  company = nil
end
```

The expectation is, if query still processing, it should stop in 10 minutes. But it stops in 20 minutes, max timeout of MySQL.

I have checked with this, it can stop in 5 seconds

```rb
Timeout::timeout(5) { sleep(10) }
```

But with this, it still stop in 10 seconds

```rb
Timeout::timeout(5) { Company.select('SLEEP(10)').limit(1) }
```

Is it possible to stop query with rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue with this one,

```rb
begin
  query = <<-SQL
    SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(600000) */ id, location
    FROM companies
    WHERE location = 'West'
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
  SQL

  result = Company.find_by_sql(query)
  company = result.last
rescue => e
  company = nil
end
```

Maybe there is another approach.

Comment: What error is caught here? Probably better to specify the exact error you are rescueing